# Show content_available notifications in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Our server is sending notifications out `content_available: true` for notifications on both android and iOS this used to work on our previous Ionic hybrid app but when we started using native iOS with swift the notifications come in but doesn't show any alert in background, is there a way to show the alerts in background without turning off `content_available` because the android app needs it

Comment: Is your background mode enabling notifications ?

Comment: I have to enable background mode for notifications? how do i do that

Answer (score 0):

If you want your iOS device to accept silent notifications, by adding the `content-available` (not `content_available`) key with a value of `1` (not `true`) then in Xcode open the project navagator (command-1), select your project, and then select your app target.  On the Capabilities table toggle the Background Modes option to on and then check the Remote notifications at the end of the list.

Remember that silent notifications come via `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler)`